# 12.04 VPN/resolv.conf issues

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, vpn, resolv.conf, dnsmasq

According to http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/ resolv.conf contains only a single record for local `dnsmasq` server

When I connect to OpenVPN server using `network-manager-openvpn` my `/var/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf` gets updated right

```
server=/example.com/10.108.23.1
server=/10.in-addr.arpa/10.108.23.1
server=10.1.0.1
```

**BUT!**

`/etc/resolv.conf` gets updated as well when, according to the article above, it shouldn't

```
nameserver 10.108.23.1 #this is useless, dnsmasq is responsible for this now
nameserver 127.0.0.1 #this should be the only line
```

And only domain names in VPN subnames are resolved

When I manually remove the first line, everything works as expected, resolving domain names in both LAN and VPN subnets

Is it a bug? Or I can have it fixed somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have resolvconf installed. Install it and then reboot.

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

If it is already installed then do the following and then reboot.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```